# Consulta utilizando dados inner join e left join juntos

Tags: php, estrutura-de-dados, join, tabela-banco-de-dados, inner-join

Estou fazendo um sistema com php e mysql para controlar a entrada e saída de veículos em uma empresa, assim existem duas tabelas, uma para registrar as informações de saída  e outra para guardar as informações de retorno. Dentro do sistema estou fazendo uma parte de pesquisa para mostrar os registros concluídos (veículos que saíram mas já retornaram) e os registros em aberto (veículos que saíram mas ainda não retornaram) sei que os registros concluídos posso representar por meio do inner join juntando dados da tabela de saída e da de retorno, mas os registros em aberto devem ser apenas os dados(linhas) de saída que não são usados na função inner join, seria mais ou menos (DADOS DE SAÍDA) - (DADOS DE SAÍDA UTILIZADOS NO INNER JOIN) alguém poderia me ajudar sobre como posso fazer isso por favor?
OBS. Os veículos são fixos então são sempre os mesmos que ficam mudando entre registros concluídos e em aberto.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um LEFT join da tabela saida com a tabela de entrada pois assim, os registros que vierem com NULL na tabela entrada, é porque o veiculo ainda não voltou.

```
select s.veiculo_id, e.veiculo_id from saida s LEFT join entrada e on e.veiculo_id = s.veiculo_id

output:
veiculo_id veiculo_id
1          1
2          NULL
```